# ClosedRange and array subscripting in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, subscript

I'm converting my code to Swift 3 and have just 3 buildtime errors left, 2 of which have to do with my lack of understanding how ranges now work. For example, I have:

```
func shuffle( _ tenseArray: [ Tense ], ...

    var indices = [ Int ]()
    for tense in tenseArray {
        if let aRange = tenseRange[ tense ] { 
            indices.append( aRange )
        }
    }
```

Where `Tense` is an enum that looks something like:

```
 enum Tense: String {
    case IndicativePresent = "Indicative Present"
    case IndicativePreterite = "Indicative Preterite"
    case IndicativeImperfect = "Indicative Imperfect"
    ...
```

And `tenseRange` is defined as:

```
var tenseRange: [ Tense : ClosedRange<Int> ] = [:] // maps Tense enums to ranges of tense indices
```

and is populated like this:

```
tenseRange[ Tense.IndicativePresent ] = ( 11 ... 16 )
tenseRange[ Tense.IndicativePreterite ] = ( 17 ... 22 )
tenseRange[ Tense.IndicativeImperfect ] = ( 23 ... 28 )
...
```

For the line in `func shuffle`

```
indices.append( aRange )
```

I'm getting the error **Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type 'CountableRange'**. I really would like to convert those ranges into ints for use in indices of an array as I was able to do previously in Swift, but I can't seem to figure out how. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare your `indices` as an `Array` of `Int`, so you cannot use `append(_:)` for `ClosedRange<Int>`.

So, I assume you want to append all values in the ClosedRange to `indices`.

In such cases, you may need to use `append(contentsOf:)`, not `append(_:)`.

[Array](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array)

> ...
>
> [func append(Element)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538872-append)
>
> Adds a new element at the end of the array.
>
> ...
>
> [func append(contentsOf: C)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687632-append)
>
> Adds the elements of a collection to the end of the array.
>
> [func append(contentsOf: S)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1690087-append)
>
> Adds the elements of a sequence to the end of the array.

Unfortunately, in Swift 3, `CountableRange<T>` is not a Collection nor a Sequence.

But Swift 3 introduced an new Range family types, `CountableClosedRange<T>` and `CountableRange<T>`, which are both Collection. And the result type of closed range operator `...` can be a `CountableClosedRange<T>` when placed in a specific context.

```
        indices.append(contentsOf: aRange.lowerBound...aRange.upperBound)
```

---

Or else, you can declare your `tenseRange`'s value as `CountableClosedRange<Int>`.

```
var tenseRange: [ Tense : CountableClosedRange<Int> ] = [:]
```